# Buscar nome do servidor

Tags: php

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para o seguinte problema, possuo esse código.

```
function encontrarValor($url){

    $dominio = explode(".", parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
    return $dominio[0];

}
```

Ele permite retornar o nome do host quase de forma perfeita. Com tudo se o endereço do host tem `www`, ele coloca o nome do servidor como `www`. 
Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para reajustar esse código, de forma que mesmo se a `url` do servidor tiver ou não `www`, consiga identificar perfeitamente o nome do servidor.

Comment: Já tentou pegar `$dominio[1]` quando `$dominio[0]` for igual a `'www'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso, acho que assim resolveria:

```
function encontrarValor($domain)
{
    if (preg_match('/(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.+)/', $domain, $matches)){
        return explode('/',$matches[4])[0];
    }
}
echo encontrarValor('http://www.teste.com.br/url-123');
echo "<br>";
echo encontrarValor('http://teste.com.br/url-123');
```

[Exemplo no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/lveGs6)

Comment: Se você faz o `explode` no ponto, então não há como `$dominio[0]` possuir um ponto para casar com a expressão regular.

Comment: Infelizmente o codigo esta apresentando erro aqui  return preg_replace('/(http(s)?:\/\/)?www\./','',$dominio);

Comment: Veja se agora funciona...